# A cardinality of a graph

Tags: graph-theory

If I have graph $G=(V,E)\\$

What is the meaning of $|G|$? (The cardinality of G).

I'd like to know few words about it.

Thank you!

Comment: $|V|{}{}{}{}{}$.

Comment: So, it's just the amount of the vertices?

Comment: That is the standard use.

Comment: **Thank you so much! you helped me a lot.**

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Generally, for a given graph $\,G=(V,E),\;$ the standard meaning of $|G|$ is simply $$|G| = |V|$$

Comment: While we're on the subject, a few authors write $\|G\|$ to denote the number of edges.

Answer (score 3):

Usually

|V| = number of vertices or graph order.

|E| = number of edges or graph size.

Some like to use |G| to mean the graph order though.